# How can I work out which user is currently logged into a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts, user

I have a machine running Windows 7 which I set up a long time ago to autmatically log into Windows.

That's still working fine, but how can I work out the username of the currently logged-in user when I'm sat at the desktop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a `cmd` window run:

```
echo %USERNAME%
```

Comment: A better option is typing "whoami" This gives a fully qualified username instaed of just the folder they are working out of :).

Comment: @Jeff sounds handy, but I was (and currently am) on a WinXP box, and `whoami` doesn't seem to be available. If that actually works you should put it down as an answer.

Comment: Correct, Vista or later :) returns like CoolDomain\Jeff or AmazingComputer\Jeff

Comment: @Jeff, indeed it does (now I'm back home on my nice warm Win7 box :), in fact it's a better way of doing it than my current answer (because what prevents some odd call to `set` changing the env variable?) - stick that in an answer and you can have a +1 from me (obviously, feel free to @ me if you do post it).

Comment: Thanks, I'll toss it in an answer so others see it later.

Answer (score 9):

1. Press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the same time
2. Type `cmd` and click **OK**
3. Type `whoami` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will return the fully qualified user name.

Answer (score 8):

Open task manager  and go to Users tab , it will display which login is being used currently.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run (WinKey+R) > `cmd /c "echo %username% & pause"`

Fastest, easiest way to do it.

**EDIT:**
Changed run command. Was `ECHO %USERNAME%| PAUSE`. Did not work due to `echo` being an internal command of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: -1: Doesn't seem to work for me; it comes up asking what program I want to open 'ECHO' with.

Comment: Whoops! Forgot that `ECHO` is an internal command and I didn't test it! This works though, I tested it on my Windows 7 box: `cmd /c "echo %username% & pause"`

Comment: Edit your answer with that and I'll remove the vote-down. FYI, you can do `/k` instead of `/c` and omit the pause.

Answer (score -3):

Click the Start button. Your username is on the right hand section of the start menu, under the picture at the top.

Comment: -1: Actually I think that gives you a display name not the actual username